# Cloud Firestore: can cache be read synchronously?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can documents be retrieved synchronously from the cache?

For Android, the documentation only gives an `asynchronous` example?

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**:

It seems to me that the `onComplete` gets called only when the data is coming from the server. It doesn't seem to get ever called with cached data.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if you could make firestore calls but just to the local cache - then you could stick to one the one API rather then switching to SQLite for  some stuff - but even if you could I think it would need to be async because even local storage calls shouldn't be done synchronously if on the main thread.

Comment: SharedPreferences on Android and UserDefaults on iOS use local storage but can be safely called on the main thread.

Comment: I don't know about UserDefaults in iOS but `SharedPreferences` in Android are singletons and are cached process-wide. So you can get the data from SharedPreferences very early because it is in memory before you need it. But this not the case with Firestore.

Comment: @Tom It seems to me that the onComplete gets called only when the data is coming from the server. It doesn't seem to get ever called with cached data. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation only gives an asynchronous example because a synchronous one does not exist. All read operations that are done either from the cache or either online directly from Firebase servers, are `asynchronous` and you cannot change this behaviour.

What you are asking can be done on a regular JVM, with regular Java synchronization primitives but this won't work on Android.

Comment: It seems to me that the onComplete gets called only when the data is coming from the server. It doesn't seem to get ever called with cached data. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `onComplete()` method is called when an operation has been acknowledged by the Firebase database servers and can be considered complete not when you are offline.

Comment: so, is it only with `addSnapshotListener` than you can retrieve cached data?

Comment: You can retrieve the results from the cached documents with either a direct get or by listening, as you already did. Furthermore, if you want to check whether you're receiving data from the server or the cache, use the `fromCache` property on the `SnapshotMetadata` in your snapshot event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to retrieve cached data via a direct get. Can you please show me how?

Comment: Your initial question was, if cached data can be read synchronously. The way of retrieving data is basically another question. Please consider posting another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.